# Let $G$ denote an arbitrary group. Prove: The center of any group $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Let $G$ denote an arbitrary group. Prove: The center of any group $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$

Let $G$ be a group and $C$ the center, i.e., for any $a \in C$ and any $x \in G$, $xa=ax$.

So, $a = xax^{-1}$. Thus $xax^{-1} \in C$. So, $C$ is normal.

Is this proof correct? It seemed too trivial for me to think so.

Something tells me I need to show that for any $y \in G$, $xax^{-1}y=yxax^{-1}$. Would this be correct? But this would really be the same as above.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: No, you showed that $xCx^{-1} \subset C$ which is enough.

Comment: This would mean that every element in the center of a group is its own conjugate. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Another way to say it: the center of the group is fixed under conjugation. Each element of the center is its own conjugacy class.

Comment: So, another way to call the center of a group is the set of all elements in $G$ that are equal to their own conjugate?

Comment: Yes, equal to their own conjugate under conjugation by EVERY element of $G$.

Comment: @JohannFranklin If you need to prove that the subgroup $H$ of elements satisfying property $P$ is normal, you have to prove that, for every $a\in H$ and every $x\in G$, the element $xax^{-1}$ satisfies property $P$. In the case $P$ defines the center, this verification is trivial because $xax^{-1}=a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group and let $Z(G)$ be the center of $G$.

If $x \in Z(G)$, then $xy=yx$ $\ \forall y \in G$. Thus $yxy^{-1}=x \in Z(G)$.

So, $Z(G) \vartriangleleft G$.